# How do you store and search number intervals in MySQL/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, intervals

I have the following scenario:

The user will input an interval and/or single comma-separated number codes for each product.

Partial table example:

```
name        | codes
-----------------------------------
Product 1   | 239,300-350

Product 2   | 430-450,500,29

Product 3   | 780,2
```

For example, when the user searches for code 321, it should return the row of Product 1.

Is there a way for doing that search with a single query?

Comment: Oh jees, what led to this design decision?

Comment: The user has tagged each item with an unique barcode number, no matter if there are 10 different barcodes of the same product, and he is keeping track of it in... an excel file.
Yeah, sounds really crazy, and can't convince him to retag (lots of items already).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest doing this with two tables instead:

```
products:
 - name
 - id

code_ranges:
 - product_id
 - range_start
 - range_end
```

Then you can get what you want (for some `$input_id`) by using a join:

```
SELECT product.id, product.name
FROM products 
JOIN code_ranges ON products.id = code_ranges.product_id
WHERE code_ranges.range_start <= $input_id
    AND code_ranges.range_end >= $input_id
```

You can have multiple rows in the `code_ranges` table for each product to represent multiple different ranges (e.g. `2-4,7-10` would have two rows, one with `range_start=2` and `range_end=4`, and another for the 7-10 range).

A product code that isn't a range would simply be treated as a range where the start and end are the same (e.g. `7` would be `range_start=7` and `range_end=7`).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but that first answer is not helpful.Because when you looking for item code range=239 then you can't difine that item also contains 300-350